# No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, connection

I have problems getting connection to my SQLite database. On my Windows PC everything works fine, but if I want to run my program on Linux(Raspberry PI) I'm getting error as shown in title.

This is my connection on Windows:

```
public static final String DB_NAME = "settings.db";
public static final String CONNECTION_STRING = "jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\oschr\\eclipse-workspace\\Dippmitteldosierer\\src\\" + DB_NAME;
```

Before I export my program for Linux I change my connection string:

```
public static final String CONNECTION_STRING = "jdbc:sqlite:/home/pi/Desktop/" + DB_NAME;
```

If there's no database I create it with this code:

```
String url = CONNECTION_STRING;
try {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    
    statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_VORWAHLMENGEN + "( " + COLUMN_VORWAHLNAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_VORWAHLMENGE + " INTEGER)");
    statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_KALIBRIERUNGEN + "( " + COLUMN_KALIBRIERUNGNAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_KALIBRIERUNGMENGE + " INTEGER)");
```

This is my build path:
[image: This is my build path]

This is my project:
[image: This is my project]

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Do you also get a `ClassNotFoundException`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using some process that you didn't explain in your question to make a jar. You are then shipping this jar to the pi and running it there.

The process you are using is just turning *your* code into a jar. It is not including all your dependencies; this is not normally done, as it makes jars gigantic, and complicates updates.

### Option 1: executable jars with classpath entries

You need to end up with a jar that has a `Class-Path` entry in the manifest that lists `jdbc-sqlite.jar`, and then ensure that this jar is available in the same directory as 'sibling' to `yourapp.jar`. How? Well, that depends on whatever process is turning your class files into jar files.

### Option 2: Don't use `java -jar` to run it.

You can do the above by hand, if you run `java -jar sqlite.jar:yourapp.jar com.foo.YourMainClass` there.

### Option 3: Striping

Update that process so that it stripes the dep(s) into a single gigantic everything jar. Generally, you need a build system such as maven or gradle to do this.

Comment: I don't know how to do Option 1. DO I have to put the sqlite.jar in an folder which contains my app? How do I have to write the Class-Path entry? Option 2 didn't work, it gave an error: Unable to access jarfile sqlite.jar:myapp.jar

Comment: Can't I do this with Eclipse automatically? Or should I use Intellij if eclipse doesn't have this function?

Comment: option 2: trivially, as you don't need to  change anything. For the rest: Yeah, but, 'build with the IDE' is not a recommended way to do this; instead, have a build (maven or gradle based). Eclipse can then treat your project as a maven project no problem.

Comment: In eclipse, right click on your project, export... -> runnable jar file -> 'library handling: extract required libraries into generated jar' will get you something like option #3.

Comment: If I extract required libraries into generated jar and I try to start my app on Rasberry Pi I get the Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile Myapp.jar. Sorry but I don't know anything about maven. Why does my app run on Windows with no problems but not on Linux....?!?

Comment: Eclipse does not generate corrupt jarfiles - if you get that error, your file transfer most likely failed. Your question is not answerable without more detail, of course.